# Is there an algebraic characterization of when a 2 x 2 matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

All matrices are over the complex numbers. There is, of course, an algebraic characterization of when a 2x2 matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{array} \right)
$$
is not invertible: $ad - bc = 0$. Is there a similar one for when that matrix is diagonalizable? more specifically I mean, is there a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d]$ such that $p(A) = 0$ iff $A$ is diagonalizable (or $p(A) = 0$ iff $A$ is not diagonalizable)?

Edit: The $p$ should be universal, and apply to every matrix - that is, I'd like to find out whether there exists a $p \in \mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d]$ such that $\{A \mid A \text{ is not diagonalizable}\} = \{A \mid p(A) = 0\}$ or $\{A \mid p(A) \neq 0\}$.

Comment: A matrix is diagonalisible over a field $k$ iff its minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors over $k$. Is that the sort of thing you want?

Comment: Is that an if and only f? $I$ is diagonalisable, but it's min poly is $(X-1)^2$

Comment: @Mathmo123 The minpoly of the identity matrix is $X-1$.

Comment: @DanielRust Are the coefficients of the minimal polynomial over the entries of the matrix?

Comment: I think the answer is no, but I don't have a proof off-hand.  The answer is yes if you ask for regular (i.e. distinct eigenvalues) semisimple (i.e. diagonalizable) matrices -- there are some equations in the coefficients in the characteristic polynomial of $A$ which would detect this.  I have to run but I will try to answer this later if no one has already.

Comment: From wikipedia: the diagonalisable matrices form a dense subset of $\mathbb{C}^4$ with respect to the Zariski topology: the complement lies inside the set where the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial vanishes, which is a hypersurface.

Answer (score 4):

For $2\times2$ matrices, it is not so hard.  If it is not diagonalizable, then the characteristic polynomial must have a double root.  This is tested by seeing if $\text{trace}(A)^2 - 4 \det(A) = 0$ (that is, the discriminant of the quadratic characteristic polynomial is zero).

Now if the characteristic polynomial has a double root, then it will be non-diagonalizable if and only if either off diagonal entry is non-zero.

Since one of the tests is that something is zero, and the other test is that something is not zero, I don't see how to get this in the form $p(A) = 0$.

Comment: This is wrong.  One can take a non-diagaonlizable 2x2 matrix as you describe and conjugate it.

Comment: @user148177 If the characteristic polynomial has a double root, then it is diagonalizable if and only if it is a constant multiple of the identity.  And then all its conjugates will be also constant multiples of the identity.

Comment: ah, youre right I misread.

Answer (score 0):

For an algebraically closed field like $\mathbb{C}$ a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $\gcd(p,p^{'})=1$, where $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ and $p^{'}$ is its derivative.

Comment: This doesn't seem algebraic to me, in the sense of algebraic geometry?

Comment: This is wrong.  A counterexample is the identity matrix in 2 or more dimensions.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I think he/she means the *minimal* polynomial of $A$.

Comment: sorry I made a typo. Thanks to Stephen